# Unable to Render Link Component React using Foreach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, higher-order-functions

I have an array of words and none words an I'm trying to construct a sentence using the using the values inside the array and make only the words click able.

Below is a sample of the Array. This data is stored in a const called **getWordsFromTokens**

```
[
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "One"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "Saturday"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "when"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "I"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "was"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "young"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "my"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "father"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "and"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "I"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "left"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "the"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "house"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "early"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "in"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "the"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "morning"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "when"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "it"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "was"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "still"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "blue"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": "-"
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "black"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "outside"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ". "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "The"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "grass"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "left"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "wet"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "marks"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "on"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "our"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "shoes"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ". "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "In"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "the"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "backyard"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "under"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "stones"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "we"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "dug"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "up"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "crawly"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "worms"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "and"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "laid"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "them"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "in"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "a"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "can"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "with"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "lumps"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "of"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "damp"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "dirt"
  }
]
```

Here is How I'm trying to construct the sentence and make only the words clickable

```
 getWordsFromTokens.forEach(item => {
        const htmlToAppend = item.type === 'word' ?
          // `<a href='/word/${item.value}'>${item.value}</a>` :
          <Link to="user" params={item.value} >{item.value}</Link>:
          item.value
          
        document.getElementById('new-sentence').innerHTML += htmlToAppend;
      })
```

What is rendered on the browser is something that looks like this and not the text

``
[object Object] [object Object], [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object], [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object], [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]-[object Object] [object Object]. [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]. [object Object] [object Object] [object Object], [object Object] [object Object], [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object].[object Object] [object Object], [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object

``

When I use the anchot tag, it works but I want to use the Link component. What could I be doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `forEach` in react, since that's an imperative approach that doesn't work in JSX. Use `map` to create an array of JSX values, and return it as JSX code.

```js
const elems = [
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "One"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "Saturday"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "when"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "I"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "was"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "young"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "my"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "father"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "and"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "I"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "left"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "the"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "house"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "early"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "in"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "the"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "morning"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "when"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "it"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "was"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "still"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "blue"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": "-"
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "black"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "outside"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ". "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "The"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "grass"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "left"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "wet"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "marks"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "on"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "our"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "shoes"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ". "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "In"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "the"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "backyard"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "under"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "stones"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": ", "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "we"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "dug"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "up"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "crawly"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "worms"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "and"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "laid"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "them"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "in"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "a"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "can"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "with"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "lumps"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "of"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "damp"
  },
  {
    "type": "non-word",
    "value": " "
  },
  {
    "type": "word",
    "value": "dirt"
  }
]

const Words = () => {
return (<p>{elems.map(el => el.type === "word" ? (<a href={"/"+el.value}>{el.value}</a>) : el.value)}</p>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Words />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the anchor tag because i read somewhere that it will cause a page reload so better use the Link component. I'm still new to react please don't mind my many questions. Again, why is it rendering Object on the screeen. I don't understand

Comment: <Link> component of `react-router` will just be rendered as an anchor tag. But yes, if you want clientside navigation don't use `a` with href, let `react-router` to manage the navigation. I used `a` just to make a workable example  to avoid importing `react-router`. Your example shows `[Object object]` since you are trying to render <Link/> as if it were html, you can't do that. <Link /> is a function that written like that can be transpiled by Babel to JS ( something like React.createElement( Link,...,... ) ). Just forget about `innerHTML` and DOM selectors if you want to use React.